# DependencyProperty: проверка наличия зарегистрированного свойства

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть пользовательское свойство зависимости в базовом классе:

```
internal class BaseItemsControl : ItemsControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Context", typeof(object), typeof(BaseItemsControl));

    public virtual Command RemoveCommand { get; set; }
}
```

В наследнике регистрируются метаданные для данного свойства зависимости:

```
ContextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DictionaryItemsControl<TKey, TValue>), null);
```

Вопрос. Как проверить зарегистрировано ли свойство зависимости для наследника или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решен. У DependencyProperty есть метод GetMetadata который в качестве параметра принимает тип DependencyObject. Далее проверяется результат обработки метода:

```
        if (ContextProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DictionaryItemsControl<TKey, TValue>)) as UIPropertyMetadata == null)
            ContextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DictionaryItemsControl<TKey, TValue>), null);
```